# Copy stuff to char*

Tags: c++, string, char

I've got a buffer of type `char*`, and a `string`. I want to place inside the buffer the `string` length + the `string`.

I wrote the following code to accomplish this but it doesn't work, because the `std::cout<<strlen(buffer)` prints "1" no matter what string I pass as parameter of the function.

```
int VariableLengthRecord :: pack (const std::string strToPack)
    {
        int strToPackSize = strToPack.length();
        if (sizeof(strToPackSize) + strToPackSize > maxBytes - nextByte)
            return RES_RECORD_TOO_LONG; // The string is too long

        int start = nextByte;

        // Copy the string length into the buffer
        copyIntToBuffer((buffer+start),strToPackSize);

        // Copy the string into the buffer
        strcpy((buffer+start+sizeof(strToPackSize)),strToPack.c_str());

        // Move the buffer pointer
        nextByte += sizeof(strToPackSize) + strToPackSize;

        // Update buffer size
        bufferSize = nextByte;

        std::cout << "Size of buffer = " << strlen(buffer) << std::endl;
        return RES_OK;
    }


void copyIntToBuffer (char* buffer, int integer)
{
    buffer[0] = integer & 0xff;
    buffer[1] = (integer >> 8) & 0xff;
    buffer[2] = (integer >> 16) & 0xff;
    buffer[3] = (integer >> 24) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Where is `buffer` defined?

Comment: In the class constructor. `buffer = new char[maxBytes];`

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` doesn't work on binary data (the length field is binary).  Keep track of the real length, or use `5 + strlen(buffer+4)` to measure only the text part.

Or, take advantage of the fact that you stored the length inside the buffer, and read the length from there.

Comment: Ok I see your point - but is the binary data being written into the buffer?

Comment: @l19: Yes, that's what `copyIntToBuffer` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

strlen is going to walk the string until a null byte (\0) is found.  You are attempting to put together a pascal string.  If you want to use the built in strlen, you will need to advance the pointer sizeof(string_length_type)

Comment: `sizeof (string_length_type)`, which may not be `sizeof (void*)`

Comment: You mean "null byte" (`'\0'`); `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant.

Comment: @Keith: Nope, `NULL` is an integral constant expression with value `0`.  So is `'\0'`.  http://ideone.com/ajR0w4

Comment: @BenVoigt: Correct, except for the "Nope". Would you recommend using the term `NULL` to refer to a null *character*?

Comment: @Keith: I wouldn't recommend using "null", regardless of capitalization, when I meant the NUL control character.

Comment: But the data I'm writing (i.e. the size of the string) is not NULL... so how come `strlen` stops?

Comment: strlen may look for valid ascii characters as well, it would depend on the implementation

Comment: @l19: `strlen` looks at each byte separately.  Since you got a length of `1`, that suggests that `integer & 0xff` wasn't zero, but `(integer >> 8) & 0xff` was.  Which would happen any time `integer < 256`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: So what's your objection to my original comment? The C and C++ standard's both define and use the term "null character", but `NULL` is specifically a macro that expands to a null pointer constant. Referring to the null character as "NULL" is a common error. (I don't think either standard refers to the null character as "NUL", though the ASCII, Unicode, and EBCDIC standards do.)

Comment: @Keith: I mean your original objection is pointless.  `('\0')` is a NULL pointer constant just as much as `(0)` or `NULL`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Look past the literal meaning. `NULL` is *intended* to be used as a pointer value, not as a character value. Your [sample program](http://ideone.com/ajR0w4) is legal, but poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can't use `cout` to directly print the `buffer`, and you can't use `strlen` either.  The problem is that you are storing binary data.

The `strlen` function will stop at the first 0x00 byte found in the buffer.

The `cout` will print garbage for non-printable values.

You will need to convert the `buffer` to an ASCII version of hex values before printing them.

Something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i ++)
{
    cout << hex << buffer[i];
}
cout << endl;
```